# Migrate text field with multiple values

Tags: 7, migrations, entities

I've got a simple Text field which allows 2 values, let's call it `field_text`. My source database has two columns, let's say `text1` and `text2`.

I want to set my [migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) field mapping so that `text1` is used as the first value for `field_text` and use `text2` as the second value for `field_text`.

In other words, something like this:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_text[0]', 'text1');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_text[1]', 'text2');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should implement prepareRow() method in your migration class. Inside prepareRow() you can read both source fields and add them to an array.
I will provide an example:

```
public function prepareRow($row) {
  $row->text1 = array($row->text1, $row->text2);
}
```

Now your source field "text1" will contain both values and it can be mapped to "field_text". "text2" has to be set to DNM (do not map).

Comment: Does this same approach work for date fields that have a beginning and an end? I can't get it to work...

Comment: Date fields are a different story. Take a look at migrate_extras.

Comment: This did the trick for me: http://drupal.org/node/1806296 But thanks for your reply :)